# Holes in phase space because of collision potential?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, collision, topology, phase-space, gas

Consider a gas. Now, we already know the particle's  duration of a collision is very small and it immediately bounces away from there. Can these be thought of as topological holes in one's phase space (since the particle barely spends anytime there)? What is the volume of these holes and do they obey extensivity?